# Trying to understand how to write some basic math using Laravel and existing syntax

Tags: laravel

OK, I'm new here - more or less complete beginner.

Can someone help with by understanding how I can accomplish some simple maths?

```
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        @if (isset($usersbyid[$l['id']]))
            <img src="/{{ $usersbyid[$l['id']]->picpath }}" width="60px" style="border-radius:30px;" />
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (isset($usersbyid[$l['id']]))
            {!! $usersbyid[$l['id']]->name !!}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        HK$&nbsp;{{ number_format($l['commission'], 0, '.', ',') }}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        {{ $l['invoices'] }}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        {{ $l['offers'] }}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        {{ $l['viewings'] }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

If I wanted to find the average of Total Commission (which is the third data cell) by amount of invoices (which is the fourth data cell) how would I do that? Would I do that within this actual string of a new table data cell or would that command be outside in placed in a file?

I hope that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to handle the logic in your controller and then pass it to your view and then display it in your view. Your view should do as little logic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add logic to your views. You should calculate everything in your backend and then pass it to view and display simple variables, you could handle it in array to create table with foreach loop in diffrent structer that will suit to you case.